# How to add a backdrop over a div (lightbox effect)?

Tags: html, angularjs, less, lightbox, opacity

i'm editing an AngularJS project and i want to add a backdrop (like Bootstrap Modal) over the main DIV when users click on search input box.

[image]

Here is the HTML code:

```
    <div class="main-box">
        <div class="search-function" ng-click="showInputForm()">
            <img src="../images/my_project/search.png">
        </div>

        <div class="search-form" ng-if="showForm">
            <form ng-submit="textSearch()">
                <input type="text" autofocus class="search-input" ng-model="text.value" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see the white box appears when users click on the search icon and now i want to add a backdrop over the main DIV, except on the white box.

Here is the LESS code:

```
.search-function {
  margin-left: 30%;
}

.search-form {
  padding-left: 15%;
  padding-right: 15%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;

  .search-input {
    color: #2b84a6 !important;
    background-color: #fff !important;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
```

How can i reach this?

Comment: I mean something like this: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/backdrop-example/15863

Comment: so you want to do a lightbox effect?

Comment: check this: https://github.com/compact/angular-bootstrap-lightbox

Comment: I'm not using Bootstrap, i found this: https://github.com/abodelot/angular-lightbox but i have already solved. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this

```
 <div class="main-box">
    <div class="backdrop" ng-if="showForm"></div>
    <div class="search-function" ng-click="showInputForm()">
        <img src="../images/my_project/search.png">
    </div>

    <div class="search-form" ng-if="showForm">
        <form ng-submit="textSearch()">
            <input type="text" autofocus class="search-input" ng-model="text.value" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And add the CSS as

```
.backdrop {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: Simple and elegant. Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very complete article about different methods of achieving what you need

[CSS Overlay Techniques](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/11/07/css-overlay-techniques/)

Comment: Yes, i mean background overlay like Bootstrap Modal. Thank you for your reply.